# !important rule in CSS not working in firefox for width style for table

Tags: css, firefox, fixed-width

Currently I am adding below style in CSS but the width is not setting properly in firefox but same is working in Chrome, IE, Mircosoft Edge. Can you please let me know how to make it work in **Firefox**

**[Please View Demo In Full Window to Produce issue in Firefox](http://jsbin.com/luvutasavu/edit?html,css)**

**HTML Code**

```
 <tbody>

                    <tr class="features" ng-repeat="list in opMessageLogs">
                        <td style="width : 183px !important;">{{list._id.$id}}</td>
                        <td style="width : 353px !important;">{{list.OPERATION}}</td>
                        <td style="width : 88px !important;">{{list.STATUS}}</td>
                        <td style="width : 153px !important;">{{list.ACCOUNTNUMBER}}</td>
                        <td style="width : 130px !important;">{{list.SENDTIME.sec * 1000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
                        <td style="width : 130px !important;">{{list.RECEIVETIME.sec * 1000 | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'}}</td>
                        <td ng-click="showText(list.REQUEST,$index)" style="width : 113px !important;"><a style="cursor: pointer;">Request</a></td>
                        <td ng-click="showText(list.RESPONSE,$index)" style="width : 128px !important;"><a style="cursor: pointer;">Response</a></td>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
```

**Firefox Issue**

As you can see in the below screenshot the width of first element is set as **183px but its reflecting as 194.867px**

***[image: Firexo Issue]***

Comment: The width reflected in the inspector also includes `padding` and `border`. In this case, it should be `183px + 2 * 8px = 199px`. I guess you set your table's width to `100%`. The `td`s will fit into the given table width - and therefore ignore the *exact* value you assign them.

Comment: But same is working in other browser, What I need to change now..

Comment: If you set you're table width to a relative value (like `100%`), the cells should be *relative* (in `%`) as well. If you want the cells width to be exactly as given in the style property, you have to make sure the table has a *absolute* width (in `px`) according to the cells accumulated value. This might result in an overflow though, if the browser window is not wide enough.

Comment: I am to have OverScroll as I have made sure overflow with Scrollbar

Comment: In this case, I have to ask you to reproduce your specific issue (in a jsbin, jsfiddle, etc.), since it's not possible to answer without being able to see the full context.

Comment: I have updated the question with jsbin demo , Can you please help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128572/discussion-between-batman-and-naeramarth7).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128574/discussion-between-batman-and-naeramarth7).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the default UA style for `td` is `box-sizing: border-box;`, Firefox seems to have issues with with it on elements displayed as `table-cell` - instead, those elements always behave as `box-sizing: content-box`.

As mentioned in [comment9156608_7554843](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554731/css-property-box-sizing-has-no-effect-on-the-box-model#comment9156608_7554843), adding `display: inline-block` for the table cells seems to be a solid workaround.

Answer (score 0):

In some case like mine, firefox just doesn't apply `width: 100%;` and `display: table;`, It just not recognized or something else, i don't know. Then i did a little search and find a way to make display table work correctly in firefox by changing the width value `width: -moz-max-content;`.

#### Here is the full code

```
display: table !important;
position: absolute;
top: 25px;
left: 0;
width: -moz-max-content;
```

Just in case if someone have same trouble like me.